# Как использовать require_once для папки выше по уровню?

Tags: php, require_once

Не умею писать на php, но пришлось.
Как использовать require_once, что бы подключить, например, /folder_1/test.php, если я это делаю из файла /second/main.php? То есть, нахожусь не в корневом каталоге?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require_once('../folder_1/test.php');
```

А вообще лучше подключать от корня. Так удобнее и надёжнее.